# Object Constructor as function in Larger Object

Tags: javascript, oop, object, constructor

This is really tricky to find because of the overlapping key search terms.  I have this circuits game I'm making.  FYI, in terms of style, I use all-caps names for objects which, though they may change a little(like, `number_of_boards` or something), are not to be reused for other things, but the property names are reused (for example, if I had my celtic knot generator and circuits game on one page, I would have `KNOT.draw` and `CIRCUIT_BOARD.draw`)

So, here's the short version of my current set up:

```
CIRCUIT_BOARD = {
    "blankGridSquare": function(){
      //Returns brand new object that is one blank grid square of the map
    }
  , "blankMap": function(width,height){
      //Returns brand new object that has a bunch of blank grid squares
    }
  , "copyMap": function(map){
      //Returns new object with the same value as parameter map
    }
  , "newBoard": function(svg,width,height,ioPlugs,map){
      //Returns new object with a target svg,
      //either a blank map or a copy of the given map,
      //a set of ioPlugs,
      //the electric current set up,
      //etc.
      //Initializes a few other things
    }
  // and other functions of course...
}
```

I don't want to get rid of having all the functions wrapped in one variable, because I want the flexibility of putting multiple games on one page.  I've read that making constructors properly involves using the `this` keyword.  But whenever I try to use `this` for these constructors, I get, for example, a map with a bunch of functions attached to it where every single gridSquare also has all those functions attached to it.

So the question is How do I make multiple object constructors as non-instance-bound functions which are all properties of another object?  I don't even know if that condensed question is worded properly.

Comment: If you call `new CIRCUIT_BOARD.someFunction()` then inside that call the value of `this` will be a new object. If you don't use `new` in front of the call, then the value of `this` will be the `CIRCUIT_BOARD` object itself.

Comment: So if I use `new CIRCUIT_BOARD.blankGridSquare` inside of the "blankMap" function, it should only give me the intended blank square without extraneous functions? ... Testing now...

Comment: Thank you, Pointy.  That's exactly what I needed.  Next time, you should put information like that in an answer.  I would have accepted it as soon as I tested it.

Comment: Well I wasn't 100% sure I understood what you were asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the exact pattern that modules use. For example:

```
export function FooCtor() {
  this.stuff = 3;
}
```

will become:

```
exports.FooCtor = FooCtor;
function FooCtor() {
  this.stuff = 3;
}
```

Including constructors (which are just functions) in an object does not cause any problems.

The confusion you're running into, [as Pointy mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863741/object-constructor-as-function-in-larger-object#comment63184759_37863741), is around what the `new` operator does to `this` within a function call. If you're calling `new` against a function that can reasonably act as a constructor, the runtime will put together a new context with mostly-empty object assigned to `this` and invoke the function with that. It's not entirely unlike doing:

```
newInstance = FooCtor.call({}, ...args)
```

Working through the spec to figure out *why* that happens:

Starting with [§12.3.3](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-new-operator) of the spec (the `new` operator), it says:

> *MemberExpression* : **new** *MemberExpression* *Arguments*
>
> 1. Return EvaluateNew(*MemberExpression, Arguments*).

`EvaluateNew` leads us to [§12.3.3.1.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-evaluatenew), where steps 3-4 say:

> Let *ref* be the result of evaluating *constructProduction*.
>   Let *constructor* be GetValue(*ref*).

Which will work its way down through any chain of property accessors (`foo.bar`, `foo[bar]`, whatever). Next, step 9 of the same section says:

> Return Construct(*constructor*, *argList*).

Leading to [§7.3.13](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-construct) and the internal behavior of the construction process.

Note that step 9 of `EvaluateNew` does *not* specify the `newTarget` parameter to `Construct`, which triggers step 1 in `Construct`:

> If *newTarget* was not passed, let *newTarget* be *F*.

Step 5 of `Construct` hands execution off to the constructor's `[[Construct]]` property, defined at [§9.2.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-construct). Step 8 states:

> If *kind* is **"base"**, perform OrdinaryCallBindThis(*F, calleeContext, thisArgument*).

So we rewind to the definition of *thisArgument* in 5.a:

> Let *thisArgument* be OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(*newTarget*, **"%ObjectPrototype%"**).

Which bounces us up to [§9.1.14](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinarycreatefromconstructor), which actually (finally) goes about creating the new object to be used as context for the constructor:

> The abstract operation OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor creates an ordinary object whose [[Prototype]] value is retrieved from a constructor’s prototype property, if it exists. Otherwise the intrinsic named by intrinsicDefaultProto is used for [[Prototype]].

At this point we're miles away from how the constructor function was accessed. `new` doesn't care, so long as it gets a function that makes sense as a constructor. If you've given it a sensible function, this chain just sets up a new object and handles all the prototype linking stuff.

Comment: Uh, this is rather confusing.  But what it boils down to is that the `new` keyword changes the reference of the `this` keyword inside the function?  It removes the function from its context and gives it a new context?  Something like that?  There's a reason I used w3schools over MDN for years...

Comment: I added a little bit of a summary before the part digging through the spec. The spec can be hard to follow, but if you read it like code, starts to make a lot of sense. Also, *please* don't use w3schools; they tend to be factually wrong and their examples have a lot of problems.

Comment: I find that they simply lack some of the more complex information.  Like if I want to find all the things I can create with SVG, I'm going to MDN instead.  It's more of an introduction to each of the various languages and stuff.  I've never seen a concrete example of something blatantly wrong on there.  But even if there is, the miscommunication that newer audiences have on more factually-correct sites causes a lot more issues than straight-up wrong answers.  At least, that was my experience when I was younger.  I can actually read the JQuery API and MDN stuff now, so I prefer that.

Comment: Anywho, even though there's more information than I asked for here (I have no need for the inner workings of keywords and operators), you did answer the question... I think...  Though if Pointy had wrapped his statement in an answer instead of a comment, I probably would have accepted that before you got here.

Comment: Oh, @Pointy 's comment is totally correct, I just expanded on it with the specifics.